# Do custom networks replace default network in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Does specifying custom networks in docker-compose remove services from the default network? I can't find any information about this.

example

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: 'nginx:alpine'
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
      - internal_network
    labels:
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
      - "traefik.backend=blog"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:test.ondrovo.com"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.frontend.passHostHeader=true"
      - "traefik.protocol=http"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/srv/www
      - ./config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./config/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d

  php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./www:/srv/www
    networks:
      - internal_network

networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: traefik

  internal_network:
    internal: true
```

in this case, is internal_network needed or can i just leave it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, the default network is removed if you specify them manually.
I went ahead and tried it.

You can specify 'default' in the networks list, however, and it apparently does not need to be declared in the top-level list.